# Can I set visual studio to use psake when building?

Tags: .net, build, psake

I would like to set visual studio to use Psake build by default when building. Is this possible slash more effort than its worth?

Comment: @R0MANARMY use psake to trigger msbuild rather than have VS trigger it directly. That way I could code post and pre-build events in powershell rather than the csproj file craziness.

Comment: Could you just add a call to a pre-build PSake script and a post-build PSake script into your project file and work from there?

Comment: @R0MANARMY - of course, but then I would be using a completely separate build chain in visual studio than outside of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible yes, and certainly worth the effort if you value consistency in the build, which it sounds like you do.

[StudioShell](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/) is the main player, and [here's](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Overview-of-StudioShell-Solution-Modules.aspx) a tidy blog post on the matter.

Comment: So that project's still kickin' huh? Any idea if it works with vs 2012?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't say - haven't tested it.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer And as of [version 1.5](http://studioshell.codeplex.com/workitem/43), it works with VS 2012.